# Get SVG representation of div using jQuery SVG

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-svg

I am trying to get  svg representation of a div.I am using jQuery SVG for this http://keith-wood.name/svg.html

I am doing this on  page load:

```
var pad = null;
    $('.MyDiv').svg({onLoad: function(svg) { 
        pad = svg; 
    } 
    });
```

and on every change inside div , i am doing this:

```
var svg = $('.MyDiv').svg('get'); 
alert(svg.text);
```

but i am getting some JS code in alert.
i tried alerting `svg.toSVG()` but i am getting this :

`<svg version='1.1'></svg>` in alert

`svg.toSVG()` seems to work but i am getting empty svg doc even if my div has data in it.

what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [innerSVG shim](http://code.google.com/p/innersvg/) might be helpful to you.