# Insert non encoded html code in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, url, encoding, get

I have a jsp page that accepts a string in the get parameter `mystring` :

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/index.jsp?mystring=
```

I am trying to place this string inside a `<pre>` tag.

```
<body>
 <pre>
      <%= request.getParameter("mystring") %>
  </pre>
</body>
```

When I call `http://localhost:8080/MyApp/index.jsp?mystring=<html>` nothing is printed.
Then I tried [URLUTF8Encoder](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=urlutf8encoder&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFEQFjAA&url=http://www.w3.org/International/URLUTF8Encoder.java&ei=9QL3T9CcBoXUrQfBxu3ZBg&usg=AFQjCNEnumDvxsVxcmuPQfm85w4nqiTi5Q) and it worked for most of the tags but when I pass something like this :

```
<script>window.serq=[];StackExchange={ready:function(f){serq.push(f)}}</script>
    <title>Get SVG representation of div using jQuery SVG - Stack Overflow</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" title="Stack Overflow" href="/opensearch.xml">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=691f98480525">
    <meta name="relativepagescore" content="5555">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11340476/get-svg-representation-of-div-using-jquery-svg">
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Feed for question 'Get SVG representation of div using jQuery SVG'" href="/feeds/question/11340476">
    <script type="text/javascript">
      StackExchange.ready(function () {
        StackExchange.realtime.init('ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com');
        StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToInboxNotifications();
        StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToReputationNotifications('1');            
      });
    </script>
```

I get a nothing in response.

After encoding the url, it looks like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/SnippetImage/image.jsp?mystring=%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26lt%3bscript%26gt%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3ewindow%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e.%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3eserq%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%5b%5d%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22typ%22%3eStackExchange%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%7b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3eready%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3a%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22kwd%22%3efunction%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e(%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3ef%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e)%7b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3eserq%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e.%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3epush%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e(%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3ef%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e)%7d%7d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26lt%3b%2fscript%26gt%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a++++%0a%0a++++%0a%0a++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26lt%3btitle%26gt%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3eGet+SVG+representation+of+div+using+jQuery+SVG+-+Stack+Overflow%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26lt%3b%2ftitle%26gt%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26lt%3blink%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3erel%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22shortcut+icon%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3ehref%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22http%3a%2f%2fcdn.sstatic.net%2fstackoverflow%2fimg%2ffavicon.ico%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26gt%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26lt%3blink%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3erel%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22apple-touch-icon%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3ehref%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22http%3a%2f%2fcdn.sstatic.net%2fstackoverflow%2fimg%2fapple-touch-icon.png%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26gt%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26lt%3blink%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3erel%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22search%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3etype%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22application%2fopensearchdescription%2bxml%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3etitle%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22Stack+Overflow%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3ehref%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22%2fopensearch.xml%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26gt%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a%0a%0a++++%0a%0a++++%0a%0a++++%0a%0a++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26lt%3blink%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3erel%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22stylesheet%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3etype%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22text%2fcss%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3ehref%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22http%3a%2f%2fcdn.sstatic.net%2fstackoverflow%2fall.css%3fv%3d691f98480525%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26gt%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a++++%0a%0a++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26lt%3bmeta%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3ename%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22relativepagescore%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3econtent%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%225555%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26gt%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26lt%3blink%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3erel%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22canonical%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3ehref%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22http%3a%2f%2fstackoverflow.com%2fquestions%2f11340476%2fget-svg-representation-of-div-using-jquery-svg%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26gt%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26lt%3blink%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3erel%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22alternate%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3etype%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22application%2fatom%2bxml%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3etitle%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22Feed+for+question+'Get+SVG+representation+of+div+using+jQuery+SVG'%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3ehref%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22%2ffeeds%2fquestion%2f11340476%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26gt%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a%0a%0a%0a%0a++++++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26lt%3bscript%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atn%22%3etype%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%3d%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22atv%22%3e%22text%2fjavascript%22%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26gt%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a+++++++++++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22typ%22%3eStackExchange%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e.%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3eready%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e(%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22kwd%22%3efunction%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e()%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e+%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%7b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a+++++++++++++++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22typ%22%3eStackExchange%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e.%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3erealtime%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e.%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3einit%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e(%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22str%22%3e'ws%3a%2f%2fsockets.ny.stackexchange.com'%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e)%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a++++++++++++++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22typ%22%3eStackExchange%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e.%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3erealtime%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e.%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3esubscribeToInboxNotifications%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e()%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a++++++++++++++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22typ%22%3eStackExchange%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e.%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3erealtime%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e.%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3esubscribeToReputationNotifications%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e(%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22str%22%3e'1'%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e)%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e++++++++++++%0a%0a++++++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pun%22%3e%7d)%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%0a++++++++%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22tag%22%3e%26lt%3b%2fscript%26gt%3b%3c%2fspan%3e%3cspan+class%3d%22pln%22%3e%0a%3c%2fspan%3e
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any way I can display html without encoding?

- I have to send a GET request only. Not a POST request.
- Without javascript.

Comment: You realize you're already using javascript, right?

Comment: I've no script in my jsp. i just need to display it inside pre tag like a text.

Comment: So you want to display html like a text, right?

Comment: @Raman . yes.. but only inside pre tag..

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526502/how-to-html-encode-in-the-jsp-expression-language

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After encoding the url, it looks like this: 
>   `http://localhost:8080/SnippetImage/image.jsp?code=%3cspan...`

Note that your parameter `mystring` does not exist in your URL string. Therefore your jsp page will pull nothing.

Also note that there is a [maximum length of an http url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url), and I'm only guessing but it looks like you might be going up against a hard limit there. If you are, the way this encoding returns may be unpredictable.

Comment: sorry.. typo on my part..that url hava mystring as parameter name.

Comment: may be the url length is problem..i will try to check it with small strings.

Comment: When you execute your jsp page, is the javascript in your browser turned off? Also, what do you see when you 'view source' on the html response you get?

Comment: The entire response is blank, or do you see the closing `</pre` tag?

Comment: And what are you seeing in your error logs? Because if no response is being returned then the jsp is failing on the server end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= request.getParameter("mystring").replaceAll("<","&lt;").replaceAll(">","&gt;") %>
```